# Java: Cursor return null

Tags: java, android, database

I have a DB. There can be empty fields. 
When I try to get value from empty field with cursor, I get `NullPointerException`.

I found solution with try-catch:

```
    try {
        subject.setName(cursor.getString(2));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    try {
        subject.setTrainer(cursor.getString(3));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
    try {
        subject.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {}
```

But I don't like it. Can there be more attractive solution?

Comment: Do you need them to be executed even though the first one fails ?

Comment: Just check for null, don't catch NPE.

Comment: Post you NullPointerExeption error here so we can see exactly what is causing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if cursor object is null, then it will give null pointer exception. If your object is not null, then you can check the objects arguments are empty or null. In this way, you can do it.

```
if(cursor != null) {
    // cursors argument you can check here.
    if(cursor.getString(2) != null) {
        subject.setName(cursor.getString(2));
    }
    ---
    ---
}
```

Comment: yah...thats interesting...timing is funny.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (cursor != null)
{
    subject.setName(cursor.getString(2));
    subject.setTrainer(cursor.getString(3));
    subject.setLocation(cursor.getString(4));
}
```

Would this work? Checking to make sure cursor is not null first?

Answer (score 0):

check null-value like this:

```
    if (cursor != null) {//if cursor can achieve null value. I don't know your code before
String str2 = cursor.getString(2);
    if (str2 != null) {
        //...
    subject.setName(str2);
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Either:

1. `subject` is null,
2. `cursor` is null, or
3. `subject.setName()` throws `NullPointerException` if the argument is null.

With the little information you've provided it is impossible to say which, but the stack trace will tell you. It's easy enough to defended against any of these conditions without a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

You could check for a **null** value before you call **getString(index)**.

```
if( !cursor.isNull(2) ){
    subject.setName(cursor.getString(2));
}
```

For more details have a look at the [API here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html).